# juntando 3 dataframes

Tags: python, data.frame

Criei a função abaixo que me retorna três data frames:

```
def top_share(x, y, z):
    x['SHARE-N'] = x.SHARE_VALOR
    y['SHARE-P'] = y.SHARE_VALOR
    z['SHARE-3C'] = z.SHARE_VALOR
    x_top = x[['DESC', 'SHARE-N']]
    y_top = y[['DESC', 'SHARE-P']]
    z_top = z[['DESC', 'SHARE-3C']]
    top_share1 = x_top.groupby('DESC').mean().sort_values('SHARE-N', ascending=False).head(10)
    top_share2 = y_top.groupby('DESC').mean().sort_values('SHARE-P', ascending=False).head(10)
    top_share3 = z_top.groupby('DESC').mean().sort_values('SHARE-3C', ascending=False).head(10)
    return pd.DataFrame(top_share1), pd.DataFrame(top_share2), pd.DataFrame(top_share3)
```

Como nos tres data frames criados as colunas DESC possuem um descritivo grande a unica maneira que posso visualiza-los inteiros seria em forma de data frame, gostaria que a função me retorna-se um unico data frame com 6 colunas, não consigo usar merger pq eles não tem um indice em comum  e quando tento usar o join ele me apresenta um erro dizendo que :

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Também tentei criar um retorno do tipo:

```
return pd.DataFrame(top_share1 + top_share2 + top_share3)
```

Porém ele me retorna um data frame com todas as colunas de share com Nan.

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar utilizar a função [concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) do pandas.

```
return pd.concat([top_share1, top_share2, top_share3], axis=1)
```